# Meaning of 'confer upon'

Tags: meaning, idioms

> The only objects which can constitute [the space-time framework essential to interpersonal communication] are those which **confer upon it** their own fundamental characteristics.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The construction *X confers Y upon Z* means that X causes object or person Z to have attribute Y.

So your example sentence means that objects cause "the space-time framework essential to interpersonal communication" to share in "their own fundamental characteristics".

Answer (score 4):

"To exchange one's opinion, thoughts, views etc." or "to give or grant a thought of yours to others".

Answer (score 0):

*Confer* means "to grant or bestow a title, degree, benefit, or right"; *upon* is a preposition that has the same meaning of *on*, but it is more formal.

> Moves were made to confer an honorary degree on her.

You can also use it to mean "to give a characteristic, feature, or quality".

**<sub>[Reference: the *New Oxford American Dictionary*, third edition.]</sub>**